# How to write a test for a nested controller index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

Right now my organizations controller lists all organizations where the current user has a membership. I know that my test is wrong, but I just can't figure out how it would be correct.

**organizations_controller.rb**

```
def index
   @user = current_user
   @organizations = @user.organizations.all
end
```

This is working fine, the model is ok and the views show the correct organizations.

I am trying to write a test for it, but somehow I am stuck. Here's my factory:

```
  factory :organization do 
    name "example"
    website "www.aquarterit.com"
    after(:create) {|organization| organization.users = [create(:admin)]}
  end
```

Here's my test:

```
describe "GET #index" do 
    it "populates an array of organizations where the user has membership" do
        organization = create(:organization)
        get :index
        expect(assigns(:organizations)).to eq([organization])
    end
    it "renders the :index view"  do
        get :index
        expect(response).to render_template ("index")
    end
end
```

The result is naturally:

```
expected: [#<Organization id: 1, name: "example", website: "www.aquarterit.com", created_at: "2014-02-20 22:10:17", updated_at: "2014-02-20 22:10:17">]
            got: nil

       (compared using ==)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `organization` you create in the test is not associated with the `user` that is returned on calling `current_user`. stub the `current_user` method to return your user

```
describe "GET #index" do 
    it "should populate an array of organizations where the user has membership" do
        organization = create(:organization)
        controller.stub(:current_user).and_return(organization.user)
        get :index
        expect(assigns(:organizations)).to eq([organization])
    end

    it "renders the :index view"  do
        get :index
        expect(response).to render_template ("index")
    end
end
```

Comment: I am afraid that doesn't work... I get: `1) OrganizationsController GET #index should populate an array of organizations where the user has membership
     Failure/Error: controller.stub(:current_user).and_return(organization.user)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method 'user' for #<Organization`